# Double Integral with infinite and function bounds

Tags: r, double, integral

I am trying to integrate double integrals with 0 to infinity and 0 to x as bounds in R. However, `adaptIntegrate()` cannot take function as bounds, and integral2 does not take infinite as bounds. Is there other functions that can integrate with these specific bounds?

Here’s the code for adaptIntegrate:

```
f <- function(x){exp((-(1/2)*x[1] - (1/3)*x[2]))}
adaptIntegrate(f, lowerLimit = c(0,0), upperLimit = c(Inf,x)
```

Also for integral2:

```
xmin <- 0; xmax <- 1
ymin <- 0; ymax <- function(x) sqrt(1 - x^2)
I <- integral2(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may nest two `integrate` to calculate double integrals, the outer partial function integrates the inner one.
Since `integrate` evaluates `f` as a vectorized function, another function nested in `sapply` is needed in order to vectorize `integrate` itself, calculate each integral point (and to set the upper bound).
Does this answer you question?

```r
f <- function(x, y){
  exp((-(1/2)*x - (1/3)*y))}

partial_x <- integrate(
  function(x) sapply(x, function(x) {
      partial_y <- integrate(
        function(y) sapply(y, function(y) 
          f(x, y)), 
        lower = 0, 
        upper = x)
      return(partial_y$value)
    }), 
  lower = 0,  
  upper = Inf)

partial_x$value
#> [1] 2.4
```

you can also use `Vectorize` instead sapply for the same purpose and not need of function nested inside sapply-

```
integrate(
  Vectorize(\(x) integrate(
    Vectorize(\(y) f(x, y)), 
    lower = 0, upper = x)$value),
  lower = 0, upper = Inf)$value
```

Same approach for arbitrary nested integrals.

<sup>Created on 2023-01-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>